# OnSubmitEditing is not firing nor is onEndEditing

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having an issue on detecting when the enter key is pressed by a user.

```
OnSubmitEditing={() => console.log('test')}
```

Should display test on my console log but it does not.

This part of my code works:

```
  onChangeText={(text) => {

this.setState({task:text})
console.log(this.state.task)
}}
```

I am unsure what method I should be using to capture the enter key.

My entire code is:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import{
StyleSheet,
Text,
TextInput,
View
} from 'react-native';

module.exports= React.createClass({
getInitialState(){
return({

tasks:['take out the trash','get groceries','Practice piano'],
task:''
})

},
renderList(tasks){
return(
tasks.map((task) =>{
return(
<View key={task} style={styles.task}> 
<Text>{task}</Text>
</View>

)

})

)

},
addTask(){
   console.log('test')
let tasks = this.state.tasks.concat([this.state.task]);
this.setState({tasks:tasks})

},
render(){
return(
<View style={styles.container}>
<Text style={styles.header}>To-Do Master</Text>
<Text>
</Text>
<TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder='Add a task'
onChangeText={(text) => {

this.setState({task:text})
console.log(this.state.task)
}}
onEndEditing={() => this.addTask()}
/>
{this.renderList(this.state.tasks)}
</View>

)

}

});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
flex:1,
},
header:{
margin:30,
marginTop:40,
textAlign:'center',
fontSize:18
}, 
task:{
height:60,
borderWidth:1,
borderColor:'black',
justifyContent:'center',
alignItems:'center'

},
input:{

height:60,
borderWidth:1,
borderRadius:5,
borderColor:'black',
textAlign:'center',
margin:10

}

})
```

All, I would really like would be able to do is know when the user presses the enter key and call a method at that time. I find it odd that I can't find this information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install [react-native-dismiss-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dismiss-keyboard) and then do this:

```
_onChangeText = (text) => {
    this.setState({task:text})
    console.log(this.state.task)
}

_handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if(event.nativeEvent.key == "Enter"){
        dismissKeyboard();
    }
}

<TextInput 
    style={styles.input} 
    placeholder='Add a task'
    onChangeText={this._onChangeText}
    keyboardType="default"
    returnKeyType="done"
    onKeyPress={this._handleKeyDown}
/>
```

Comment: I was unaware of dismisskeyboard. Is this common knowledge? Thank you for taking the time to help.